# How to move images uploaded to google form into individual seperate folder?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have Google Form for new property listings.

When the form is submitted, I would like to have a folder created in the parent folder titled the name inputted (Form Entry Field 1) and contain the images uploaded by that form (Form Entry Field 3). So effectively, a folder created on every form entry.

In the Google form, using Script Editor and I have inputted this code below with the parent folder ID. I have also setup a Trigger for onFormSubmit.

However, Line 5 is throwing up an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItemResponses' of undefined`

Please understand, I am a beginner at this type of code, so I'm not sure and a little out my depth.

Is this task possible?

Thanks

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "1VXzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";  

  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();

  Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
  itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem is the way you get the answers: `formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses();`.

Since each of the answers occupies a place in the array it is easy to keep track of them. If question 1 occupies place 0, question 2 occupies place 1, and so on.

The following example is tested and works:

```js
function handleForms() {
  /* Initialize an empty array for save the folders  */
  let folders = []
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm()
  for (const res of form.getResponses()) {
    /* Getting the responses in this example only are two of them */
    const folderName = res.getItemResponses()[0].getResponse()
    const imgResponse = res.getItemResponses()[1]
    /* Create a new folder with the name */
    const folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName)
    /* Iterate to move the files to the new folder */
    for (const img of imgResponse.getResponse()) {
      DriveApp.getFileById(img).moveTo(folder)
    }
    Logger.log(folders)
    folders.push(folder)
  }
  /* Iterate over the folders to move them to the main one */
  const mainFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('<YOUR_FORM_FOLDER>')
  folders.forEach(f => DriveApp.getFolderById(f.getId()).moveTo(mainFolder))
}
```

###### Update

If you want to keep the original files, just add this two lines inside image iteration:

```js
const newIMG = DriveApp.getFileById(img).makeCopy()
newIMG.moveTo(folder)
```

###### Update 2

For control if the file already exist you can implement a control to check if the folder exists just before creating it.

```js
const checker = DriveApp
  .getFolderById(MAIN_FOLDER)
  .getFoldersByName(folderName)

if (checker.hasNext()) continue
/* Create a new folder with the name */
const folder = DriveApp.createFolder(folderName)
```

Comment: Thank you Emel for your response. I added your code in the google form -> script editor and inserted the main folder ID into line 19. However, there is an error in the execution log when I try to run the function. `Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFileById on object DriveApp` - Debug shows this at line 13 `DriveApp.getFileById(img).moveTo(folder)`

Comment: This seems odd, is working perfectly for me. Can you ensure that the images still exist? Also, try to create a new form with two questions, one for the title and another for the images, after add my script and try it again, this way we ensure that is not an unexpected error.

Comment: Hi Emel. Done as above and upon run Execution Complete. I done a test with the two questions and I can confirm it works. A folder is created inside the parent folder with the title and images inside (My Drive -> Parent Folder -> Title -> Images). Works like magic. However, I have found a problem / glitch. When I tested the form again for the second live run, it created the folder (ENTRY 2) with the images as hoped BUT it also created another folder named (ENTRY 1) with no images insdie.  I tested a thrid time and it done the same. It created folders for ENTRY 1, 2 (empty) & 3 (with images)

Comment: Hi there, this is happening because the images are being moved to the last created folder. This line does exactly that `DriveApp.getFileById(img).moveTo(folder)`, so I didn't consider it a glitch, is the expected behavior. If instead of dirclty using `moveTo`, you use something like `const copiedIMG = DriveApp.getFileById(img).makeCopy()` and after `copiedIMG.moveTo(folder)`, it will keep the original if that is what you want.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if I described it properly. The images are not moving the last created folder. For example; on Entry 2, a folder is created with Entry 2 containing it's images but it creates another folder (Entry 1) which is empty. Which means there is then a total of two Entry 1 folders. One Empty and One containing Entry 1 images. The same happens on Entry 3 except it creates a blank folder for Entry 1 & 2 this time, but the original folders are still present with the images inside. So after 3 tests, there is 6 folders (1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3) Image of Drive -> https://ibb.co/KrZzmvK

Comment: From what I understand you are  doing this workflow: fill out the form, run a test, fill out a second one, run a test an so on, right? The first run it creates one folder(1), the second run creates two folders(1,1,2), the third run (1,1,1,2,2,3) and so on. This is the expected behavior due the script is not checking if the folder is already been created. You need to implement some form of control over it, maybe with `DriveApp.getFolderById('').getFilesByName('')`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the workflow and the behaviour that's happening. Unfortunate, not sure how to implement that form of control.

Comment: Just update my question to add the control system. Please, accept my answer if it was helpful to you.